# Monitor IIS site (Up/Down) with Appdynamics

Tags: iis, appdynamics

Am using Appdynamics to monitor my application hosted in IIS.

I have installed necessary dotnet agent in server and am getting the related metrics, but what I couldn't get is if the **application is running or stopped**. I couldn't figure how to configure if an application is up or not. Same case with the application pool.

All I can see is if their is no load on the server the AppServerAgent status is 0, but this cannot be used to check application is down or not.

Even tried to keep the HealthRules to check AppAvailability

[RuleConfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNhgZ.png)

But couldn't get the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the agent is reporting / up by using the "Availability" metric in your Heath Rules (Agent > App > Availability).

In terms of Application Monitoring, AppDynamics monitors Business Transactions primarily. You will need to configure appropriate Business Transaction detection rules to have these register.

You can then set Health Rules based on any Business Transaction activity (which effectively represents Application activity).